# Serious(?) Warnings in Terminal when mounting a drive and opening nautilus

Tags: command-line, nautilus, 16.04

I am trying to create a script that mounts another partition of my HDD and then opens a specific folder inside there so I don't have to click ~10 times to mount and get there. These are the commands I type and the results I get from terminal when testing for them before I create the script:

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid>
Mounted /dev/sda3 at /media/<user_name>/<partition_name>.
$ nautilus "/media/<user_name>/<partition_name>/<path_to_folder>"

(nautilus:3863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:3863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:3863): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:3863): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:3863): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Despite these errors the window does open at the correct spot ! Is it safe to ignore them? They look like things I should fix. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and all packages are updated/upgraded.

By searching on the net I found some posts with similar error but they either where slightly different things or weren't answered([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439686/gtk-icon-theme-get-for-screen-error-for-nautilus), [2](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1225845)). Those posts do contain a helpful information however. An easy way to reproduce this error is to open a terminal and type:

```
$ nautilus .
```

Comment: `gtk` applications are incredibly chatty since... ever. I have seen these errors a lot, never had a problem --- barring the more or less random `nautilus` crash that is probably related, but definitely not dangerous. I hope.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution for chatty commands is to send their terminal output to /dev/null. For nautilus I have the following line in my `.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias nautilus='nautilus >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

That should make nautilus silent again (this was no issue for me until I updated to 16.04).