# GLib-GIO-CRITICAL and GtK terminal errors but Nautilus successfully launched in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, command-line, nautilus

Terminal Errors when launching file manager from Terminal; should I file a bug report? What is the problem?

```
user@computer:~$ nautilus &
[1] 28351
user@computer:~$ 
(nautilus:28351): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:28351): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:28351): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:28351): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:28351): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Comment: It is not serious, you can ignore it or hide it sending the output to dev>null. https://askubuntu.com/a/824911/88368s